# Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with 500

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

Here is my `gorilla-websocket` websocket handler:

```golang
func wshandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    wsupgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    }
    c, err := wsupgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        var m WebsocketGeneralClientMessage
        err := c.ReadJSON(&m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }
        switch m.Type {
        case "register":
            err := Register(c, m)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the `type`, I want to responds differently to different types of messages. I have only the `register` type. For some reason, the `Register` function gives me the following error:

```
Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 200 with 500
```

```golang
func Register(c *websocket.Conn, m WebsocketGeneralClientMessage) error {
    var d RegisterData
    json.Unmarshal(m.Data, &d)
    if len(d.Email) < 6 || len(d.Email) > 64 {
        _error := "The email length must be between 6 and 64 characters"
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }
    if len(d.Password) < 6 || len(d.Password) > 32 {
        _error := "The password length must be between 6 and 64 characters"
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": "The password length must be between 6 and 64 characters"}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }
    err := checkmail.ValidateFormat(d.Email)
    if err != nil {
        _error := "The email format is not correct"
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }

    var rawUUID pgtype.UUID
    var exists bool

    err = Pool.QueryRow(context.Background(), `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT "email" FROM "account" WHERE "email"=$1)`, d.Email).Scan(&exists)
    if err != nil {
        _error := "An error occured while creating the account. Please send a message in #bugs at our Discord."
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }

    if exists {
        _error := "An error occured while creating the account. Please send a message in #bugs at our Discord."
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }

    err = Pool.QueryRow(context.Background(), `INSERT INTO "account" ("email", "password") VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING "uuid"`, d.Email, d.Password).Scan(&rawUUID)
    if err != nil {
        _error := "An error occured while creating the account. Please send a message in #bugs at our Discord."
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }

    uuid, err := rawUUID.Value()
    if err != nil {
        _error := "An error occured while saving the account to the database"
        c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "error", Data: map[string]interface{}{"text": _error}})
        return errors.New(_error)
    }

    c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "success", Data: map[string]interface{}{"uuid": uuid}})
    return nil
}
```

I know the problem is in the second half of the function after `var exists bool` because I removed that part and the program didn't give an error. What might be the problem? Obviously the error appears because I am supposedly overriding response but every `c.WriterJSON` ends with a `return` so there should not be any response override.

Here is the full error:

```
2020/09/21 13:58:01 [Recovery] 2020/09/21 - 13:58:01 panic recovered:
GET /ws HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.41
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Upgrade
Origin: http://192.168.0.41
Sec-Websocket-Key: 9E7mNgJ4qH4VsbWDJuEaWQ==
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: okhttp/3.14.4


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:212 (0x104c992)
    panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15/libexec/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:720 (0x104c812)
    sigpanic: panicmem()
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.8.1/pgxpool/pool.go:355 (0x14c21ba)
    (*Pool).Acquire: res, err := p.p.Acquire(ctx)
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4@v4.8.1/pgxpool/pool.go:419 (0x14c2459)
    (*Pool).QueryRow: c, err := p.Acquire(ctx)
/Users/virtumonde/Desktop/dev/terminus/terminus-server/ws_routes.go:46 (0x14cfa0b)
    Register: err = Pool.QueryRow(context.Background(), `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT "email" FROM "account" WHERE "email"=$1)`, d.Email).Scan(&exists)
/Users/virtumonde/Desktop/dev/terminus/terminus-server/ws.go:34 (0x14cf3e4)
    wshandler: err := Register(c, m)
/Users/virtumonde/Desktop/dev/terminus/terminus-server/main.go:44 (0x14d07ea)
    main.func1: wshandler(c.Writer, c.Request)
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x13a5eba)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/recovery.go:83 (0x13b1cc4)
    RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x13a5eba)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/logger.go:241 (0x13b0dc4)
    LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x13a5eba)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:409 (0x13a8c79)
    (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/Users/virtumonde/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:367 (0x13a84ec)
    (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2843 (0x12676a2)
    serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1925 (0x1263c6c)
    (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 (0x106bb60)
    goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

Comment: I may offer a clue: when you write an HTTP response to the client, first goes the "status line" then the header (a block with `key: value` fields), then an empty line and then the (optional) response body. The `http.ResponseWriter` is defined (please refer to its docs) in the following way: if has the `WriteHeader` method which accepts the status code and writes to the client, the status line and the header fields accumulated so far. After that, the status line and the header cannot be "resent" as they have already been streamed to the wire.

Comment: …The `Write` method is defined to check whether the `WriteHeader` has already been called, and if it hadn't, it gets called automatcally, with the status code 200 OK. Basically it means that _any_ call to `Write` on the `http.ResponseWrite` makes that response "become" a 200 OK response with its header streamed to the client. What I'm leading you to, is that ostensibly some bit of whatever "middleware" is used in your case happens to call `Write` on the `http.ResponseWriter` earlier than the point at which you want to decide on the request's status. Reconsider the request handling logic.

Comment: You will need a very strange spacetime which allows to change the past. Not worth the trouble. Redesign.

Comment: As I understand there is no async code in this function, right? Everything is executed line after line. Do I stand correct?

Comment: The middleware that calls write on top of the previous one is located between ```var exists bool``` and ```c.WriteJSON(WebsocketGeneralServerMessage{Type: "register", Status: "success", Data: map[string]interface{}{"uuid": uuid}})```. All the code inside is database code. Maybe this behaves this way because the code is async? I do not think it is.

Comment: Can you take a look at the full error? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My `Pool` variable (using which I connect to my Postgres database)

```
var Pool *pgxpool.Pool
```

was overshadowed on initialization by another local variable.

```
Pool, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), "postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database")
```

so I changed the initialization to

```
var err error
Pool, err = pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), "postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database")
```

Apparently, the database code was executing more than once because of this.